# I have unit test according conditions of this code, but it shows me it does not have unit test for one of these condition

Tags: junit

I have unit tests according to this line:
if (sortBy.compareToIgnoreCase(PROPERTY_VALUE) == 0)
However, it shows me as unCoverage by unit test in my code, and in this line I have this notification : 1 of to branches missed. What can I do for that?

```
// Sort the list
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(sortBy)
                && !(DEFAULT_SORT_FIELD.equals(sortBy))) {
            if (sortBy.compareToIgnoreCase(PROPERTY_NAME) == 0) {
                Collections.sort(configurationProperties,
                        ConfigurationPropertyComparator.NAME);
            } else {
                if (sortBy.compareToIgnoreCase(PROPERTY_VALUE) == 0) {
                    Collections.sort(configurationProperties,
                            ConfigurationPropertyComparator.VALUE);
                }
            }
        } else {
            Collections.sort(configurationProperties,
                    ConfigurationPropertyComparator.ID);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (sortBy.compareToIgnoreCase(PROPERTY_VALUE) == 0) {
```

This requires *two* tests.  One where the condition is `true` and one where the condition is `false`.  Presumably you're only testing the `true` condition since that's the only condition you use.

The compiled code blocks, however, include branches for both the `if` *and* the `else`, even if you never use the `else`.  In order to reach 100% test coverage, you have to include a logical path where the (empty) `else` is reached.